# Pytorch LSTM time series, forecasting values of next n rows returns same value n times

Tags: pytorch, time-series, lstm

I am trying to create an LSTM model to predict a specific value (first column of the dataset, idx 0) for the next 10 rows. The input sequence contains 10 rows of the time series and 19 features

```
for i in range(sequence_length, len(data) - 10):
    sequences.append(data.iloc[i-sequence_length:i, 2:2+input_size].values)
    labels.append(data.iloc[i + 1: i + 11, 0])
```

Sample data:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21

1.084,1.08405,1.0841,1.08405,1.0841,1.084,11240,6.249999999985434e-05,-1.0164458235761842e-05,-5.1788748878102555e-05,1.0840285714285716,1.0840928571428572,1.0840280952380952,1.08405,-0.000937629492890638,0.8237791754445127,-0.009223815892633767,49.223395431868134,-3.13680151375703,0.010743580701520136,1000.2306464528247

1.084,1.08405,1.08405,1.08405,1.0841,1.08405,14158,-2.4999999999941735e-05,-9.32997172098382e-06,-6.046625792230974e-05,1.0840285714285716,1.0840857142857143,1.0840309523809522,1.084046103896104,-0.0008606520795521739,3.185291329162407,-0.009223815892633767,49.223395431868134,-2.9477598235694686,0.009208783458445832,1000.2306464528247

1.0839,1.08395,1.08405,1.08395,1.08405,1.08385,19095,-0.00015749999999981057,-1.6547055257998267e-05,-7.543797446324434e-05,1.0840142857142856,1.0840690476190478,1.0840204761904761,1.0840337662337662,-0.0015264100999568611,8.156945531675506,-0.009224666758912318,41.76004501048701,-4.958497925954123,-0.26489247132130206,1000.2306464528247

1.08395,1.084,1.08395,1.084,1.084,1.08385,12756,-0.0001474999999999671,-1.8024291017937344e-05,-9.06405060916429e-05,1.0840035714285714,1.0840547619047618,1.0840185714285715,1.084027489177489,-0.0016626858514864735,7.660743847017261,0.009225943352706798,46.15600965239905,-5.393125751532237,-0.13593640398949522,1000.2767846809004
```

The loss decreases greatly (managed to get it down to 3.1…e-8) yet the predictions for one sequence are always the same numbers.

For example the labels for a sequence could be

`[1.084,1.0845,1.084,1.08395,1.0839,1.0838,1.0839,1.084,1.0845,1.084]`

And the preds that I get back

`[1.08395,1.08395,1.08395,1.08395,1.08395,1.08395,1.08395,1.08395,1.08395,1.08395]`

At the moment I use batch size of 32, so I get roughly the following:

```
[
 [1.08395,1.08395,..]
 [1.0841,1.0841,..]
..
]
```

I do not understand why the predictions do not follow the momentum of the value that they meant to predict. Obviously, getting the same value when trying to predict the next n rows is not useful even if the loss is decreasing…

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

class CustomLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, dropout, num_layers):
        super(CustomLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()  # ReLU activation layer
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size * 2)  # Batch normalization layer
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size * 2, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers * 2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).double().to(x.device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers * 2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).double().to(x.device)

        x = torch.nn.functional.normalize(x)
        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
        out = self.relu(out[:, -1, :])  # Apply ReLU activation
        out = self.bn(out)  # Apply batch normalization
        out = self.dropout(out)  # Apply dropout
        out = self.fc(out)

        return out

input_size = 19  # Number of input features

# Loss calculation for regression model
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

data = pd.read_csv('chapter6/a_without_normalization.csv')

# Split the dataset into train and test sets
train_size = int(0.9 * len(data)) 
test_size = len(data) - train_size
train_dataset, test_dataset = data[:train_size], data[train_size:]

def create_sequences(data, sequence_length):
    sequences = []
    labels = []
    for i in range(sequence_length, len(data) - 10):
        sequences.append(data.iloc[i-sequence_length:i, 2:2+input_size].values)
        labels.append(data.iloc[i + 1: i + 11, 0])
    return np.array(sequences), np.array(labels)

sequence_length = 10
train_sequences, train_labels = create_sequences(train_dataset, sequence_length)
test_sequences, test_labels = create_sequences(test_dataset, sequence_length)

# Convert to PyTorch tensors
train_sequences = torch.from_numpy(train_sequences)
train_labels = torch.from_numpy(train_labels)
test_sequences = torch.from_numpy(test_sequences)
test_labels = torch.from_numpy(test_labels)

# Create a TensorDataset from sequences and labels
train_dataset = TensorDataset(train_sequences, train_labels)
test_dataset = TensorDataset(test_sequences, test_labels)

batch_size = 32
dropout = 0.2
hidden_size = 64
weight_decay = 0.001
lstm_layers = 2
lr = 0.001

output_size = 10  # Number of output features
num_epochs = 101
model_eval_every = 2
print_loss_every = 1
save_model_every = 2500

# Create a DataLoader with the current batch size
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

train_dataloader_len = len(train_dataloader)

# Instantiate the model
model = CustomLSTM(input_size, hidden_size, output_size, dropout, lstm_layers).double().to(device)

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

# Define the scheduler
scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=30, gamma=0.6)

print(f'Training with weight_decay {weight_decay}')

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        # Unpack the batch
        batch_sequences, batch_labels = batch[0].to(device), batch[1].to(device)

        # Pass the batch through the model
        output = model(batch_sequences).squeeze()

        # Compute the loss
        loss = criterion(output, batch_labels)
        total_loss += loss.item()

        # Backpropagate the loss
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    # Update the learning rate
    scheduler.step()
```

Could this be because of the difference between the values are so small?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering might be related to the scale of your input and output values. When dealing with LSTM networks, especially when using activation functions like ReLU, the scale of the input data and target values can have a significant impact on the training process.

Here are a few suggestions to address this issue:

**1. Normalization:**

Normalize your input and output data. You are already normalizing your input data (x = torch.nn.functional.normalize(x)), but you might want to check whether it's enough. Ensure that both input and output values are scaled to a similar range. You can use techniques like Min-Max scaling or Z-score normalization.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data.iloc[:, 2:] = scaler.fit_transform(data.iloc[:, 2:])
```

**2. Loss Function:**

Consider using a loss function that is more suitable for regression tasks and is less sensitive to the scale of the target values. You could try Mean Absolute Error (MAE) which is a little less sensitive to outliers than Mean Squared Error (MSE).

```
criterion = nn.L1Loss()  # Mean Absolute Error
```

**3. Model Complexity:**

Experiment with the complexity of your model. Too complex models might overfit the training data, leading to poor generalization. You can try reducing the number of hidden layers or neurons. Try for example:

```
hidden_size = 32
dropout = 0.5
lstm_layers = 1
```

**4. Gradient clipping:**

Implement gradient clipping to avoid exploding gradients, which can happen when the scale of your gradients is too large. Here is the code updated to perform clipping. I would test a clipping value in [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]

```
clip_value = 1.0

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        # Unpack the batch
        batch_sequences, batch_labels = batch[0].to(device), batch[1].to(device)

        # Pass the batch through the model
        output = model(batch_sequences).squeeze()

        # Compute the loss
        loss = criterion(output, batch_labels)
        total_loss += loss.item()

        # Backpropagate the loss with gradient clipping
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        # Clip gradients to prevent exploding gradients
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), clip_value)

        optimizer.step()
```

Here is an example of what it is gradient clipping. https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-gradient-clipping-b8e815cdfb48

[image]